# XML Namespace prefixes: difference between two snippets

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

What is the difference between

```
<ns:MyRequest xmlns:ns="http://my.namespace">
        <node_a>2016-02-29T08:50:00</node_a>
        <node_b></node_b>
</MyRequest>
```

and

```
<MyRequest xmlns="http://my.namespace">
        <node_a xmlns="">2016-02-29T08:50:00</node_a>
        <node_b xmlns=""></node_b>
</MyRequest>
```

Comment: There's no difference. In both cases the attached namespace uris are attached for the equivalent nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an XML information model perspective, they are the same: If there was such a thing as an "expanded element name" syntax, the document would look like this in both cases:

```
<{http://my.namespace}MyRequest>
    <{}node_a>2016-02-29T08:50:00</{}node_a>
    <{}node_b></{}node_b>
</{http://my.namespace}MyRequest>
```

Comment: Just as I suspected, but I needed independent confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

As @potame mentioned in the comments (and now @forty-two just reaffirmed in another answer which helpfully shows the expanded names (+1)), **the two forms are equivalent**.  There are an infinite number of lexical ways in which one can specify equivalent namespaced XML.

**Notes:**

- It is the associated namespace URI, not the prefix that matters in the end.
- The second form uses a default namespace, which would apply to the
  children nodes, `node_a` and `node_b`, if not for the `xmlns=""`, which
  resets the default and leaves `node_a` and `node_b` in no namespace,
  just like in the first form.

Comment: Just as I suspected. As a side note it turns out that somehow it makes the diffierence to SOAP service I am trying to use...

Comment: Interesting, believable, and unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's the conventional wisdom that the choice of prefixes should make no difference, many programming data models (including DOM and XPath) expose the prefix, which makes it very easy to write applications that cease to work if someone chooses a different prefix. So when we say "there is no difference", what we mean is "a properly written application should treat them as equivalent". Unfortunately, though, an awful lot of programmers dealing with XML data don't understand the subtler features of XML, so improperly written applications are rather common.